# How to validate radio button in html using name and type

Tags: javascript, html, validation, radio-button

i am having three group of radio buttons and using the below code for get the checked value of the radio button. But this takes the all radio buttons as a single group how to seperate and validate using its group name.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
         var x = $("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
    });
   });



<label><input type="radio" name="present" value="1" />yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="present" value="2" />no</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="present" value="3" />No idea</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="outing" value="1" />yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="outing" value="2" />no</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="outing" value="3" />No idea</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="member" value="1" />yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="member" value="2" />no</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="member" value="3" />No idea</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `var x = $("input[type=radio][name='present']:checked").val();` for the `present` group (modify the `name` ad lib).

Answer (score 1):

you can do as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
         var x = $("input[type='radio'][name='present']:checked").val();
         var y = $("input[type='radio'][name='outing']:checked").val();
         var z = $("input[type='radio'][name='member']:checked").val();
    });
   });
```

x,y,z has respective checked values of radio button